# AFNetworking and -[__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f54358

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, afnetworking, unrecognized-selector

I have some days now this strange problem `2014-03-24 16:50:56.097 MyApp[1610:4703] -[__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f54358`.

I have debugging my library, which is a static library where I package as a .framework and distribute to developers.

Debugging is little hard, in point of breakpoints, so I have added the static library .xcodeproj file to a sample client application and tried to work with it. After some research and trying to figure out where this is occur I have no other reason than believe that it's an AFNetworking problem!

I have this code in my static library:

**EDITED:**

```
// Selector parameter (NSData *)theData

    NSMutableURLRequest *aRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:theURL                                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0f] autorelease];

            [aRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [aRequest setValue:key forHTTPHeaderField:@"Custom-Header"];
            [aRequest setValue:@"plain/text" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData data];
            [postData appendData:theData];
            [aRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:aRequest];

                [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                    {
                    _pendingDispatchesCount --;
                    NSLog(@"%@, %ld", kServerRespondedMsg, (long)operation.response.statusCode);
                    BOOL statusCodeAcceptable = [[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 100)] containsIndex:[operation.response statusCode]];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                            [delegate analyticsOperationCompleted:statusCodeAcceptable forData:analyticsData];
                        });
                    }
                failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                    {
                    _pendingDispatchesCount --;
                    NSLog(@"%@, %ld", kServerRespondedMsg, (long)operation.response.statusCode);
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                            [delegate analyticsOperationCompleted:NO forData:analyticsData];
                        });
                    }];

                [operation start];
```

If I just comment the `[operation start];` the sample client starts properly. If I let the operation to start I get the `2014-03-24 16:50:56.097 MyApp[1610:4703] -[__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Drives me crazy at the moment, because this error occurs only to one developer where he reported it and he actually created a sample that reproduces it.

**EDIT:**
Found a way to get the stacktrace and it seems that this is not caused by my application:

Backtrace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010201c495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101d7b99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020ad65d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010200dd8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010200d938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010200e9d1 CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes + 81
    6   CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fdf1ab _ZL13appendEscapedP10__CFStringPKS_ + 40
    7   CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fdef69 _ZL25initializeUserAgentStringv + 124
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001026d58d6 __pthread_once_handler + 65
    9   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001025e3156 _os_once + 73
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001026d5875 pthread_once + 57
    11  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fdeb23 cleanUpRequest + 105
    12  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fde824 _ZN17HTTPNetConnection19prepareTransmissionEP17HTTPNetStreamInfoP17__CoreWriteStream + 1224
    13  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fdda65 _ZN13NetConnection7enqueueEPvh + 539
    14  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fdd7e4 _ZN17HTTPNetStreamInfo16_streamImpl_OpenEP13CFStreamErrorPh + 88
    15  CFNetwork                           0x000000010403c295 _ZThn120_N17HTTPNetStreamInfo16_streamImpl_OpenEP13CFStreamErrorPh + 13
    16  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fbdfc2 _ZN14CoreStreamBase21_streamInterface_OpenEv + 80
    17  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fdd057 _ZN12HTTPProtocol10openStreamEv + 255
    18  CFNetwork                           0x0000000104048c41 _ZN12HTTPProtocol26useNetConnectionForRequestEP13NetConnectionP15__CFHTTPMessageh + 1753
    19  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fdc268 _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry28dispatchConnectionToProtocolEP13NetConnectionP12HTTPProtocolP18HTTPRequestMessageh + 276
    20  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fdc027 _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry34notifyNextProtocolOfOpenConnectionEP13NetConnectionh + 301
    21  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fd9230 _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry25enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage + 650
    22  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fd8bf0 _ZN19HTTPConnectionCache34_onqueue_enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage + 178
    23  CFNetwork                           0x000000010404e843 ___ZN19HTTPConnectionCache25enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage_block_invoke + 26
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fc2f74 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    25  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fd43e7 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 133
    26  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fd4217 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 247
    27  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103fd403a _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fabd21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fab5f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fc746f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fc6d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    32  Foundation                          0x000000010193089c +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
    33  Foundation                          0x00000001019832df __NSThread__main__ + 1167
    34  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001026d4899 _pthread_body + 138
    35  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001026d472a _pthread_struct_init + 0
    36  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001026d8fc9 thread_start + 13
```

**EDITED:**
Link with the full PLCrashReporter crash report symbolicated. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_4YDWJioTI1c0hia25NSXFTWVk/edit?usp=sharing

Any help or thought appreciated, thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: What's the stack trace? You are probably supplying an `NSNumber` instance where an `NSString` is expected...

Comment: Yeah, if It gave me a stack trace I would be easy to find the problem, it's not output anything in the console instead I get only this -> http://i345.photobucket.com/albums/p394/George_Taskos/ScreenShot2014-03-24at51415PM_zps5792f566.png

Comment: I have found the issue, I was checking the length in a nil NSString! It was right there and couldn't just see it. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that was it... You can message a `nil` object anytime.  If you message it with `length` you would get back 0.  The assertion is telling you what is happening (as Wain indicated earlier).  You are sending `length` to an instance of `NSNumber` that was created as a boolean.  That object does not respond to the `length` method.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Nothing actually fixed! I still try to find the problem

Comment: Edited, any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please provide the full crash log? It includes other valuable information to help diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Edited with full symbolicated crash report link from PLCrashReporter.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the stack trace and think about what might go on. The stack trace is not some magical thing, it's something directly related to your code.

The crash is caused by someone sending a "length" message to an `NSNumber` containing a `Boolean` value.

On the stack trace we see `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`. So it seems that `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` was called with an `NSNumber` object instead of a string.

Why would `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` be called? It's usually called for strings containing URLs and similar things that cannot be transmitted as they are and need translating, like space to %20.

So you probably passed an `NSNumber` to something that would be sent over the network. Like a header property, a `URL`, and so on.

Go through all the things that you set up in the `URL` request. Problem is probably in the "aRequest", especially since you decided to hide it. (That's the subconscious mind not wanting us to see your mistake which is of course counter-productive here).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In my defense I just inherited someone's else code that's why it's hard to track the bug, still figuring out what he was doing in there :D. I will hunt this now with your information, I just need to find where he calls CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes.

Comment: Edited the question with the aRequest construction.

Comment: @TaskosGeorge: It very well may be called behind the scenes. The more important thing is to verify that things which are supposed to be URLs actually are (for example, there's one in the first line of the code you posted).

Comment: @TaskosGeorge: Also, if this project uses manual retain-counting rather than ARC, this could be an overrelease problem, in which case you'd want to turn on zombies.